# TransformedBitmap to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, rotatetransform

I have an Observable Collection of BitmapImage type in which i store some images, this collection is bound to the UI.

Now the problem is, i want to make changes to these images, for example rotate.
Now in order to rotate, i have to make a TransformedBitmap out of the BitmapImages, this is not the problem.

When i am done, i want to place them back into the collection, here comes the problem.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TransformedBitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage

I have searched long and wide, and cannot find a solution for this problem.

The question: How can i convert a TransformedBitmap back into a BitmapImage?

Comment: For your collection you should use `BitmapSource` instead of `BitmapImage`

Comment: i Want to store the actual image, not the source of it. And i'm guessing from the name, that the BitmapSource stores just the source.

Comment: `BitmapSource` is the base class of `BitmapImage` and you can use it for an `Image` in the UI. Think of it as the source of the pixels

Comment: I will try it. The thing is, i MUST give the UI and image object, not the path to it, because if I give the <image ....../> the path, it will lock the specific file, so it cannot be altered(rotate, delete etc.) anymore

Comment: `BitmapSource` is not a path as I said. use `new Image(){Source = bitmapSource}` to creat a image

Comment: Do you know how i can make it so that it would be new BitmapImage(){Source = bitmapSource}?:)

Comment: what's your use case, why do you need that?

Comment: Because i need to perform various taskst with the images, and i need their path in order to do so.

Comment: you can cast the `BitmapSource` back to `BitmapImage`, the `TransformedBitmap` obviously has no path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binding the `Source` property of Image controls in your UI it is sufficient to use `BitmapSource` (or even `ImageSource`) as element type of the ObservableCollection.

You could then add any derived bitmap type:

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapSource> Bitmaps { get; set; }
...
Bitmaps.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(...)));
Bitmaps.Add(new TransformedBitmap(Bitmaps[0], new RotateTransform(90)));
```